# Server error log full of SSL info...

Tags: ssl, logging

my apache error log is growing at about 1Mb/min and not sure what the cause is. There's about 50 of the following lines being written to the log file per second! It's an Opencart web site. I notice the SSL Access Log file is big too, over 70Mb for today.

```
[info] Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 20 (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[info] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Connection closed to child 20 with standard shutdown (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 10 (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[info] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Connection closed to child 10 with standard shutdown (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[info] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Connection to child 34 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[info] Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 34 (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[info] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Connection closed to child 34 with standard shutdown (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[info] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Connection to child 24 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
```

The SSL cert was only recently installed and seems to be fine on the front end. I'm not sure if it's a hosting issue or a site issue? Any help appreciated. I do not have shell access.

Comment: Was the LogLevel directive changed from its default ("warn") to "info" or lower recently? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel